# Give access to a firebase project to another developer. Is it safe?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I work with a developper, but I don't know him personally. Now I want him to make me a feature on my flutter website and for that I have to give him access to my firebase project. My problem is, that once the website is online, I don't want him to have any access anymore. If I delete him as member before I put the website online, he won't have any access anymore right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you delete a collaborator from a Firebase project, they won't be able to access that project in the Firebase console anymore, nor deploy updates through the Firebase CLI or API.